# Mongoid 2.2.0 autosave throws stack level too deep exception

Tags: mongoid

On Mongoid 2.2.0, migrated from Mongoid 2.0.0.rc7, and now when I save my an instance of my models, I get a stack level too deep exception, which didn't happen on rc7.

Here are my models, pretty simple:

```
class Firm
  include Mongoid::Document
  references_many :accounts, :autosave => true
end

class Account
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  referenced_in :firm, :autosave => true
end
```

Here's some sample code:

```
firm = Firm.create! :name=>'XYZ'
acc = Account.create! :name=>"Hello", :firm=>firm
```

The exception is thrown on `Account.create!`

Creating the account results in a huge stack trace:

```
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_67'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_67'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_103'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_67'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_67'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_103'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_67'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_67'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_103'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_67'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_67'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_103'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_67'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_67'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_103'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_67'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_67'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_103'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_67'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_67'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:29:in `_callback_after_103'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1615:in `each'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/relations/auto_save.rb:28:in `_callback_after_103'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `_run_save_callbacks'
    org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1698:in `__send__'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2097:in `send'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:93:in `run_callbacks'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/modification.rb:23:in `prepare'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/update.rb:43:in `persist'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:86:in `update'
    /home/x/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.7/gems/mongoid-2.2.0/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:151:in `upsert'
```

Do I need to only define `autosave` in one Model? Because if I do, then that seems to work. I understand why putting autosave in both models will result in an infinite loop, but what's the correct solution?

Comment: It seems you have 2 callbacks calling each other indefinitely so indeed I think defining autosave on only the parent model is the way to go, as explained on the [mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common)

Comment: So, if I do `a = Account.new(firm: Firm.new); a.save!`, will that save the Firm also?

Comment: I'd say yes because the new account have to keep a reference of the firm it belongs to. It make sense to save every parents of a newly saved child in order to preserve database consistency. You should definitely check it beforehand though.